# How to display statistical significance and the mean score using ggstatsplot

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have the following R code:

```
##Installe the package
install.packages("ggstatsplot")
library(ggstatsplot)

## Create data
df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:10,100,rep=TRUE)),
group=sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"), size=100, replace=TRUE))

##Code
ggbetweenstats(
  data = df,
  x = group,
  y = X1,
  plot.type = "box", # for boxplot
  pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
  type = "nonparametric", # for wilcoxon
  centrality.plotting = TRUE, # remove median
  sphericity.correction = FALSE,
  pairwise.display = "significant",
  title = "Title"
) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 10),
    breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 1)
  )
```

which produces this picture  [image: Picture]

I would like to display the difference between the groups with a line over bars if the difference is statistically significant. I also would like to show the mean score with a dashed line. I tried a few codes but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential issues here. The first, and most obvious, is that your sample data doesn't *have* any significant pairwise differences, so none are drawn. The second is that by adding the `scale_y_continuous`, you are cutting the lines off even if they were there. If we pass a sample data set that has significant differences and remove the `scale_y_continuous`, the comparisons are there:

```r
library(ggstatsplot)

set.seed(1)

## Create data
df <- data.frame(X1 = rnorm(100, rep(c(4, 5.1, 5, 4.9, 6), each = 20)),
                 group = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 20))

##Code
ggbetweenstats(
  data = df,
  x = group,
  y = X1,
  plot.type = "box", # for boxplot
  pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
  pairwise.display = "significant",
  type = "nonparametric", # for wilcoxon
  centrality.plotting = TRUE, # remove median
  sphericity.correction = FALSE,
  title = "Title"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The p-value for one of my pairwise differences is 0.06. I added the argument ``conf.level = 0.90`` in order to see if the plot shows a significant relationship but it didn't work. Do you how to make it work?

Comment: @Santiago99 did you remove the `scale_y_continuous`? I didn't get a significant p value when I ran your example because it is different every time (you did not `set.seed` to make the random draw reproducible)